# Developing a simple photo ASP.NET/MVC application, how to do this?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, photo

I found this web site (photoblog) 
http://www.OneReaction.net/

and I am very curious how this is done:
1) From source code you don't see the image URL
2) How to overlay the copyright information on the image without changing the underlying photo?

Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this link: [Watermarking Images in ASP.NET with an HttpHandler](http://blog.donnfelker.com/post/Watermarking-Images-in-ASPNET-with-an-HttpHandler.aspx). It describes a technique for adding watermarks to every image of your site. By changing the path of the `HttpHandler` in the `web.config` to something less general (e.g. `/photos/*.jpg`), you can constraint the effect to a subset of images.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the ImageHandler.ashx is intercepting the requests and placing the copyright information into the image before delivering it to the browser. The handler is likely set up to capture all attempts to browse to a .jpg file.

The [documentation on the drawing namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) should help you figure out the actual code for inserting text into an image.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is in source code

```
<img id="image" title="Condemned to Contrast II" src="Resources/ImageHandler.ashx" 
    alt="Condemned to Contrast II" style="border-width:0px;" />
```

Try [this link](http://www.onereaction.net/Resources/ImageHandler.ashx)